# convert RGB to grayscale in C

Tags: c, equation, graphic

I used many formulas to convert from RGB to grayscale, but didn't get good results compared to GIMP.

I already tested the following formulas:

```
gray = (int)(0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.144 * b);

gray = (int)(0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b);

gray = (int)(0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b);

gray = (int) (0.35*r + 0.50*g + 0.15*b);

gray = ((r * 61) + (g * 174) + (b * 21)) / 256;

gray = (int)((4897 * r + 9617 * g + 1868 * b) >> 14);

gray = r; if(g > gray) gray = g; if(b > gray) gray = b;
```

Comment: I don't think this is really on-topic here, since it's a (subjective) graphics question rather than a programming question. That said, GIMP is open-source, so did you consider just looking at what it does?

Comment: Can you not just use `libgimp` to do it for you?

Comment: Since the eye have a maximum of sensitivity at green, it's seems like first or fourth formula right.

Answer (score 15):

In order to correctly convert RGB to grayscale, you should transform the gamma corrected R,G and B values into the linear color space, apply the conversion in the linear space, and then apply a gamma correction to the result.

The [sRGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) colorspace has a transform that only approximates a gamma curve. See the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) article for the particulars. Wikipedia also has a specific [section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale) on the subject of sRGB to grayscale.

Basically, to convert a sRGB component to linear format:

```
double sRGB_to_linear(double x) {
    if (x < 0.04045) return x/12.92;
    return pow((x+0.055)/1.055, 2.4);
}
```

Then, to convert sRGB to linear grayscale:

```
double R_linear = sRGB_to_linear(R/255.0);
double G_linear = sRGB_to_linear(G/255.0);
double B_linear = sRGB_to_linear(B/255.0);
double gray_linear = 0.2126 * R_linear + 0.7152 * G_linear + 0.0722 * B_linear;
```

Then, apply the sRGB gamma correction again:

```
double linear_to_sRGB(double y) {
    if (y <= 0.0031308) return 12.92 * y;
    return 1.055 * pow(y, 1/2.4) - 0.055;
}
```

I.e.

```
double gray_color = round(linear_to_sRGB(gray_linear) * 255);
```

Comment: Could you give me a reference or equation?

Comment: I found the math equation from Wikipedia site below the Converting color to grayscale title. But i don't understand what it means. Thanks you.

Comment: Those coefficients (0.2126, 0.7152 and 0.0722) are originally from the linear-RGB -> XYZ space transformation matrix (the middle row of the matrix, which computes the Y).

The resulting "intensity" value is actually the 'Y' value from the XYZ vector.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#The_reverse_transformation

Answer (score 2):

There is [a GIMP tutorial](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Color2BW/#grayscale) that describes several different ways that The GIMP can convert a color image to grayscale. One method is a weighted desaturation like you've tried already, and the article gives some weights that can be used to approximate The GIMP's conversion.

The GIMP's `gegl` library, which is the basis for all of its image operations, has [a rather elaborate mechanism for converting color to greyscale](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gegl/diff/operations/workshop/c2g.c?id=7907ae9a13e3d1fb469b09713746028e27db3704), which takes into account the color of neighboring pixels and uses an iterative approach that seems to emulate the process of developing black and white photographs.

Answer (score 1):

The [gimp help for the desaturate tool](https://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-tool-desaturate.html) states three available formulas corresponding to the options named "Lighness", "Luminosity" and "Average". Those would be:

Lightness: `0.5 * (max(R,G,B) + min(R,G,B))`

Luminosity: `(0.21 * R) + (0.72 * G) + (0.07 * B)`

Average: `(R + G + B)/3`